# ParentId in CustomerAddress Entity in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

There is an Attribute called `ParentId` in `CustomerAddress` Entity. Will this contain the AccountId or ContactId?

If yes, if I create another `Account` or `Contact` with the exact same Address Details, a new record will be created anyway as the `ParentId` will be different?

Or if the `AddressId` is going to be stored in the `Account` Entity, can the same address be used by different accounts or even contacts?

Can Account1 and Account2 or Account1 and Contact2 have the same address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between `Address` entity and `Account` or `Contact` entities is one-to-many. It means that one `Account` can have multiple `Addresses`, but one `Address` can be assigned to only one `Account`.
Answering to your question: **no**, multiple `Account` and `Contact` records can not share the same `Address` record.